# I have wanted to download a file from a link

Tags: java, servlets, http-get

I have a servlet which is downloading a file from specified location. 
Currently my URL is http://localhost:8080/DownloadFromservlet/download?file=c://tmp/DownloadFileServlet.pdf
and it should be like : http://localhost:8080/fileserver/download?file=c:/tmp/DownloadFileServlet.pdf

i need to replace DownloadFromservlet with fileserver. Here is my code

```
@WebServlet("/download")
public class download extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String sourceFile = request.getParameter("file");
    sourceFile = sourceFile != null ? sourceFile.trim() : "";
    File fo = null;

    if (sourceFile.length() > 0)

        fo = new File(sourceFile);

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInoutStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fo));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    // ;
    while (bytesRead != -1) {
        bytesRead = bufferedInoutStream.read(buffer);
        servletOutputStream.write(buffer);
    }
    servletOutputStream.flush();

    if (servletOutputStream != null) {
        try {
            servletOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable tx) {
        }
    }

    if (bufferedInoutStream != null) {
        try {
            bufferedInoutStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable tx) {
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Could you please help me how can i change it?

Comment: You need to change your context path for your application on your server, which server are you using for deployment?

Comment: Thanks for the help i got some solution from internet ..just wanted to check is it the right way...by right clicking on project >properties>web project setting>context root path need to be changed and after that we can clean and restart the server.